# Heat death of the Universe in LCDM

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, space-expansion

I have often read that the heat deat of the Universe occurs in cosmologies where its age can be arbitarily large, even with a cosmological constant. However the standard LCDM cosmology's conformal age is bounded, even in the arbitarily far future. It seems to me that for the Universe to necessarily reach equilibrium then it must also conformally reach equilibrium, but I don't see how that is a given if the conformal age is bounded. My question is the LCDM model how can the Universe definitely reach heat death?

Comment: Thinking about it, in the conformall mapping finite volumes of space shrink to a point, which is presumably in equilibirum with itself.

Comment: The cosmological model that makes the most use of conformal ideation would seem to be the 2020 Nobel winner Penrose's "Conformal Cyclic Cosmology" (with that award having, however, taken other work into account as well).  Although not quite a "multiverse" model in spite of its division of its single universe into "temporal iterations", it is definitely past- and future-eternal (i.e., lacking any "heat death"), as detailed in a paper by Daniel Linford, "Big Bounce or Double Bang?", that's freely visible at https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07748  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the conformal time is bounded in the future means that there are regions in the universe which we will not be able to get information from, so particles here cannot equilibrate with particles there.

However, the form of equilibrium you reach in LCDM is not one with a bunch of particles colliding and reaching equilibrium. Rather, you reach an equilibrium with no particles, only the cosmological constant. Basically, all the particles will leave the horizon (and the wavelength of any photons will stretch beyond the horizon). The temperature of this universe will be given by the Hubble rate, $T \sim H$, similar to the Hawking temperature of a black hole.

Comment: So perhaps the way to understand it conformally is that because the cosmological horizon shrinks to a point in the infintley far future when conformally mapped to Minkowski space, there is a zero probabilty of any particle being at that point and the horizon just has the temeprature of empty space, which is solely depends on the cosmological constant.

Comment: @lhle --I can see how this answer is consistent with isotropy (things being the same in all directions), but not with homogeneity, yet I had thought both were assumed in the "Standard" (LCDM) model, which I had thought was not a "multiverse" model.  For particles to be extant beyond a cosmological horizon (AKA a "particle horizon"), I can't see how a multiverse (also implied by the OP's capitalization of "Universe", suggesting its nature as a locality) would not be required.  Are my assumptions correct with respect to your answer, or am I wrong about LCDM referring only to a single universe?

Comment: I had been unaware that the assumption of homogeneity is considered, by supporters of the Standard Model, to remain consistent with an assumption that we're in an "under-dense region".  Sounds a little like a cop-out to me, but it would, nevertheless, allow consistency with Ihle's answer.  A better one might not be feasible until the current "crisis in cosmology" is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There are TWO LCDM possible assumptions related to what the universe will be like towards the end part of time.

1. All matter gravitationally bound together in a galaxy, or a collection of galaxies, will ultimately form into a single black hole. All other matter will become so far away from this black hole so that it will have no significant influence on it. This is one possible result. It depends on the assumption that Hawking radiation is only a false conjecture and is not a real phenomenon. The universe would then have many such black holes, each not having any relationship with any other black holes. There is no currently present firm experimental or observational evidence that Hawking radiation is a real phenomenon.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation.

2. If Hawking radiation is a real phenomenon, than eventually the black hole described in #1 will eventually radiate all of its contents away, and the radiation particles will not interact with anything. Thus the  universe will eventually everywhere become a vacuum.